# Develop client-server app for android ... where do i start?

Tags: android, web-applications, client-server

First, let me say that I know nothing.  I am reasonably intelligent, and I can learn .... but what I need to know is what exactly it is that I need to learn.  Consider me a hobbyist that just got started.  I have a degree in math so logic makes sense to me, but it was all abstract math so I never even used Matlab once in school.

I want to develop an application for android.  I want this application to take input (text and camera images) from the user, and store that input along with certain meta-data (i.e. time of input, geo-location of device when inputted).  I also want that data to be transferred to a server (I have complete admin access to a server, but haven't learned much about it yet either) and stored there in a manner which can be accessed by a desktop or web application which I will also need to develop.  The android device may not always have an internet connection at the time of input (but will be taken to a wi-fi hotspot for uploading when completed), and after uploading the data to the server I will have no further need for the data on the device.

I have done a bit of research, and discovered the following gaps in my knowledge, and remedied them in the following ways:
a) I'm going to need to know how to program in android - I have worked through [these tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) at developer.android.com, purchased and partly read this book(**1**), and just purchased this book(**2**).
b) I believe I am going to need to know something about JSON - I have just purchased this book(**3**), after reading just a little bit about JSON on the web.
c) I will need to learn what I need to with the server to prepare it for the data - No idea where to start.
d) I will need to decide how to access the data, and learn how to develop whatever it is. - No idea where to start.

I am not able to post multiple links, so I have moved all the books down here ...
**1** google.com/search?q=isbn+9780321741233
**2** google.com/search?q=isbn+9780321749673
**3** google.com/search?q=isbn+9780470526910

My question(s):
If this was your project, how would you go about doing this?  What languages will I have to learn?  Can you recommend any books, online tutorials, etc. for each of those languages in the way that they would apply to my project?

Thank you for taking the time to read my query, and thank you for any help you may provide.

Comment: This is way too vague for SO and probably belongs as a question on some kind of discussion forum. At best, the only part of this that's really appropriate here would be "What's the easiest language to use on the server end for an Android client-to-server app?" and that's way too subjective and argumentative to start on. But nearly any Android book will have a section on making network calls and parsing the responses, and any book on any modern web framework will have a section on making them talk REST-fully to clients. Good luck.

Comment: Split this into multiple questions (Don't forget to search for answers to similar questions first).  I'll get you started:  How do I capture images from the camera in Android?  How do I capture geo location in android?  How do I POST binary data (a JPEG most likely) to a web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Book: **Pro Android 2**. I have it, I've read it, and it shows you how to do just about everything. I bought it for the sole purpose of developing a client/server application in Android, and I completed the app in two weeks.

Comment: sounds like exactly the book i'm looking for ... just ordered it ... thank you